# Domain name not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, dns

My website can be accessed via `https://example.com` but can not be found using either `https://www.example.com` or `www.example.com`, if I use either of these it just throws up a "site cannot be reached" page.

Is this something I can change in the `.htaccess` file or is it the DNS of the domain?

I have tried adding the following code to the `.htaccess` file, but it makes no difference

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How could your server possibly redirect my request for `www.example.com` elsewhere, when my request for `www.example.com` does not reach your server in the first place ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...or is it the dns of the domain?

Yes, this is "most probably" a DNS issue. The request is not even reaching your server by the sounds of it. `.htaccess` is consequently never processed.

You'll require a `CNAME` record that points the `www` subdomain to the domain apex (`example.com`) - so that both `www.example.com` and `example.com` point to the same place.

However, you also need to make sure that your server is accepting requests to both `www.example.com` and `example.com` - this doesn't happen by default. Although if you have configured your account via some hosting control panel then this has probably already been done for you. Otherwise, you need a `ServerAlias` record defined in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` container. For example:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```